# Looping through variables

Tags: r

I have a subset of data in r like so:  "Subset <- subset(x, select = c("var1" , "var2", "var3"))".  Now I have two functions that create two different graphs.  One is a table and the other is a bar graph.
One function is "quick_table(variable_name, label, sort)"
The other is created by "table.desc <- describe(as.factor(eval(parse(text = "variable"))))" and then "pandoc.table(table.desc$values)".
I want to be create a for loop that loops through the three variables to create six graphs.
The problem is that "quick_table" depends on variable name so "var1", "var2", "var3" and "table.desc" depends on "x$var1", "x$var2", x$var3".

My code is:

```
for(variable in Subset) {
variable_name <- assign(sub("x$", replacement = "", x$variable, fixed = TRUE), variable)
label <- variable_name
sort <- variable_name

print(quick_table(variable_name, label, sort)
table.desc <- describe(as.factor(eval(parse(text = "variable"))))
print(pandoc.table(table.desc$values))
}
```

This doesn't seem to loop through my variable list.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't  use `assign`, put things in a `list` instead.

Comment: I don't know what `x` is in your example, but if you use `[` or `[[` rather than `$`, you can use character strings, e.g., `v = "var1"` then `x[[v]]` is equivalent to `x$var1`. See also `fortunes::fortune(312)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `eval(parse(text = )))` to call a variable from the string of its name.

For example, if you wanted to call the subsets of a variable, each named `"x$var1", "x$var2", "x$var3"`, in the same `for` loop, you could do:

`for(i in 1:3){
    eval(parse(text = paste0("x$var", i)))
}`

This would call `x$var1`, `x$var2`, and `x$var3`. You could then use these calls to make any tables you want. I hope this helps!

Comment: You're not wrong. But this isn't the way you *should* do this.

Comment: @Dason How would you do this? Interested to know. Thanks!

Comment: The way implied by @Gregor in the comments is much preferable to using eval/parse.